# Given $f(x) =\frac{2}{x}$, find $f'(x)$ by determining $\lim \limits_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$

Tags: calculus

I already solved this problem and got $\frac{2}{a^2}$. However I am not sure if I solved it correctly.

Comment: Evidently not since you got the sign wrong.

Comment: It should be $-\frac{1}{a^2}$.

Comment: It's wrong, show us your work, then we can point out the error.

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim \limits_{x\to a} \frac{\frac 2x-\frac{2}{a}}{x-a} = \lim \limits_{x\to a} \frac{\frac{2a - 2x}{xa}}{x-a} = -2\lim_{x \to a} \frac{x-a}{xa(x-a)} = -2\lim_{x \to a} \frac{1}{xa} = -\frac{2}{a^2}$$

Comment: in -2lim x→a (x-a)/(xa(x-a)). why is -2 a negative not a positive.

Comment: @alex Were it positive, we would have $a-x$ in the numerator rather than $x-a$. We want $x-a$ so we can divide it out with the $x-a$ in the denominator.

Comment: oh i see what i did wrong